# Segmentation Fault on fscanf loop in c, CS50 Speller code

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf, cs50

I'm doing the cs50 speller problem and it seems everything is working except when I run Valgrind it says there is a segmentation fault, when I try running the code the same error also occurs.
This is an exercise from cs50 where I have a function which takes a "dictionary" file, which is read word by word by a loop and stored in a hashtable, to read each word, I used a while loop using fscanf taking a string from the pointer of the dictionary, to a string called words (which is bigger than any word on the dictionary), the loop keeps running until reaching EOF:

```
//Puts dictionary words into hashtable

bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *dictionaryPointer = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    if (dictionaryPointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory or not found %s \n", dictionary);
        return false;
    }
    //LENGTH is 45, the maximum amount of letters in a word.
    char words[LENGTH + 1];
    //Here is the segmentation fault problem
    while( fscanf(dictionaryPointer, "%s", words) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            printf("Not enough memory in node. \n");
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(n->word, words);
        int hashValue = hash(n->word);
        n->next = table[hashValue];
        table[hashValue] = n;
        sizeDictionary++;
    }
    fclose(dictionaryPointer);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's a `struct node`? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Does the segfault occur in this function?  Where?  Which line of code?  Did you run this in a debugger?  Is `table` explicitly initialized with all NULLs?  Is the `word` member of `struct node` a char array or a pointer?  Show your `hash` function and the definition of `table`.

Comment: OT: regarding:  `printf("Not enough memory or not found %s \n", dictionary);` and similar statements:  This not 'necessarily' the actual reason for the failure of the `fopen()` statement.  Strongly suggest calling: `perror( )` which will output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks was the cause of the error.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the error and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding:  `while( fscanf(dictionaryPointer, "%s", words) != EOF)`  when using the `%s` input format conversion specifier,  always use a MAX_width modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, because this specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.   This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow (and the resulting undefined behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your hash function is returning an index that's out of bounds. `table[hashValue]` If `hashvalue` is greater than the size of table, then this will seg fault.

If you change the return statement in your hash function to something like `return hashvalue % N;` where N is the number of items table, that should fix it.